# How to save value of p:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this selectOneRadio:

```
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  

        <h:outputText value="Options: " />  
        <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{formBean.number}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneRadio>  

    </h:panelGrid>
```

How I can save value in bean, without submit button?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent submit event or just don't want to add a button?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `<p:ajax />` inside the `selectOneRadio`

Answer (score 0):

Just add one row inside your p:selectOneRadio

In your case it should be this:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{formBean.setNumber(formBean.number)}"/>
```

It worked for me in this case:

```
        <p:selectOneRadio id="answer" value="#{test.selectedAnswer}"  layout="grid" columns="1"> 
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="#{test.activeAnswers.get(0).getText()}" itemDisabled="#{progressBar.disabled}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{test.activeAnswers.get(1).getText()}" itemDisabled="#{progressBar.disabled}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="#{test.activeAnswers.get(2).getText()}" itemDisabled="#{progressBar.disabled}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="#{test.activeAnswers.get(3).getText()}" itemDisabled="#{progressBar.disabled}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{test.setSelectedAnswer(test.selectedAnswer)}"/> 
        </p:selectOneRadio>
```